# Is "I was scared by ..." in the passive voice?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, participial-adjectives

I'm having a discussion with someone and we are having a few disagreements over whether this sentence is passive voice or not:

> I was scared by the noise.

We've discussed linking verbs, whether [**scared**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scared) is an adjective, whether it is the past participle of the verb *[**scare**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scare)* in the active voice, etc.

So, is that sentence in the passive voice?

Comment: What do you make of the wording "The noise scared me"? How does it differ from "I was scared by the noise"?

Comment: @SvenYargs I do understand the point you are making. However, my confusion arose because I thought that "scared" was an adjective and "was" was a linking verb, therefore the sentence was neither active nor passive...

Answer (score 2):

In the active voice this would be:

> The noise scared me,

If it is important to place "me" first in the sentence, the sentence can be rewritten in the passive:

> I was scared by the noise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, I will take the question to the website that you have linked.